# How to stop SparkContext

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How to stop any spark context running currently.

Information
API : Scala
Spark version : Spark 2.3

Actually I have created spark contexts. In order to stop them I should enter e.g. instance.stop() but couldn't remember the instance name of spark context. So how can I stop  running spark context?

Or is there any method to reset everything I have done in spark-shell and start from first?

Comment: How did you create the context in such a way that you don't remember the name of the variable?

Comment: IIUC, maybe you are looking for `[k for k,v in locals().items() if type(v) == SparkContext]` or `[k for k,v in locals().items() if str(type(v)) == "<class 'pyspark.context.SparkContext'>"]`?

Comment: No actually I created one yesterday which I forgot. But today i created with as &quot;sc&quot;.. but when I tried to do sc.stop() I got the same error

I am using Scala spark

Comment: So you mean yesterday's spark session is still running? Are you running `yarn`? Try `yarn application -list` from the terminal (on unix-based system) to see the names of the running applications. After you get the `Application-Id`, you can run `yarn application -kill <application-id>`.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer your question, but it may help prevent this issue in the future.

You can (should?) use the `atexit` module to ensure that your spark context's `.stop()` gets called automatically when you exit python.

```python
import atexit

#spark configuration code here
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

atexit.register(lambda: sc.stop())
```