# Stopping a SparkContext in Python interpreter

Tags: python, shell, apache-spark, pyspark, interpreter

I have a function runTests(sc) in a test_spark.py file

I am opening a python interpreter in the directory where test_spark is located and running the following commands.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()

from test_spark import runTests
runTests(sc)
```

The code in runTests method is being executed as i intend, however i am unable to stop the SparkContext sc. I tried writing sc.stop() at the end in my runTests() function.

I tried passing `sc.stop()` in python interpreter. But it is not stopping the SparkContext.

Below is my code i am running to check

```
sc
<SparkContext master=local[*] appName=pyspark-shell>

sc._jsc.sc().isStopped()
False

sc.stop()
sc._jsc.sc().isStopped()
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sc'

sc
<SparkContext master=local[*] appName=pyspark-shell>
```

I am able to close the context only by exiting the python interpreter. Problem with this is that for every small test in my code i have to open a interpreter and run the import commands again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52956494/1190388

Comment: did you find a solution? I run in the same problem and don't understand how to test the closing of spark context...